# Can't change the port number

Tags: redis

I changed the port number from 6379 to 6380 but redis still tries to connect through the default port.

It says connection refused and couldn't connect through 127.0.0.1 6379. What can I do?

Comment: What have you done to affect that change? Did you restart the server? Have you edited the .conf file?

Answer (score 1):

The command `redis-cli -p 6380` will not start a Redis server that will listening to port 6380.

If you want to change the port you must firts kill the redis instance running on default port and then locate the `redis.conf` file.

Edit the lines:

```
# Accept connections on the specified port, default is 6379.
# If port 0 is specified Redis will not listen on a TCP socket.
port 6379

cluster-config-file nodes-6379.conf
```

with your new port.

Finally, start Redis with the edited config file:

```
./redis-server /path/to/redis/redis.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a process already using 6379. On MacOS, run:

```
lsof -i :6380
```

Then kill whatever is using that port. Make sure you kill the redis instance running on 6379 and restart it on 6380 once you're sure that port is free.